# jQuery selectmenu plugin value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu

I'm using the jQuery UI Selectmenu Plugin for styling my select fields. Now I have a general question to bring this code `$(this).val()` to work with this plugin. After the `onChange` event it should me give out the value of the current select field.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just try it youself ? `console.log( $(this).val() )` in the `onChange` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu) -

**VALUE**
Retrieves or selects the value of the current option.

```
// read
$('select#speedA').selectmenu("value")
// write
$('select#speedA').selectmenu("value", "VALUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_id').selectmenu('widget').find('option:selected').val()
```